# jsTree drag and drop "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Tags: jquery, jstree

when I try to drag an item on my jsTree I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`.  I've looked into it a little bit and it looks like it's thrown just after/during `dnd_show` is called (see here http://www.jstree.com/documentation/dnd#api). My custom `crrm.move.check_move` handler *is* being called and seems to be working fine.  Any ideas on what I should try from here? it was working before... which is the odd thing

Comment: More info: the 'Uncaught TypeError' is being thrown in Google Chrome.  I get this error in Firefox: `a.nodeName is undefined` and this error in Opera `Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'a.nodeName' to object`.  This seems to suggest I'm returning true from the `ccrm.move.check_move` handler, which isn't the case

Comment: Another note: if I enable the 'types' plugin, but don't use it.. everything is ok; however once I use the types plugin: ({types {use_data: true, types: { ... }}), then it breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.  I stopped using the ccrm plugin.  Using the `valid_children` option with the types plugin does the trick.  Also for some reason `use_data` (types option) needs to be `false`